# Changing pitch, speed, reverb or all in audiofile then saving it in android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I am working on an audio manipulation application. I record the audio using MediaRecorder and play the recorded audio file in MediaPlayer, I am able to change the pitch, speed and reverb in MediaPlayer but I am not able to save the manipulated audio. I need the edited sound saved in my device.

Is there a way to do the same?

If not is there any 3rd party API by which this is possible?

If not is there any package in nodejs, python, java or c++ to do the same so that I can run the 3rd party code on my app engine and store the edited audio in my cloud storage.

Please help!

**Edit 1 :**

So after searching all through the internet. I settled with FFMpeg, using FFMpeg-Kit library that supports Android Q as well. You can find all audio manipulation commands online.

I still am unable to figure a way to change properties in realtime like a equilizer.